# Magento2: Benefits of using UI Cmponents in Frontend

Tags: magento2, store-view, uicomponent

I am Working on developing a new extension, I need to know What are the benefits have while using UI components in storefront.

I have Searched about Magento 2 UI Components Using in Storefront. I think **Customer_form** only used UI Components Using in Storefront.

`vendor/magento/module-customer/view/base/ui_component/customer_form.xml` this used in Checkout Page.

But, Magento2 used More Forms, Like

1. Customer Register
2. Login
3. contact us
4. Search  and advanced Search form
5. Quantity Update.,,,,

Its all have Normal forms. So, Suggest Me What are the Benefits have using UI Components in Storefront.

Answer (score 3):

One reason why not all form is using UI component is a lack of resources on rewriting. But in the future, almost all form will use UI components.

Because UI components  are rendered in the browser, it's better from a performance point of view and more flexible.

Comment: do you know a tutorial (exclude official) that show how to create a form with ui component for frontend?

Answer (score 2):

Ui components also make it easier to extend it. So you can manipulate or extend existing forms without having to overrule the phtml. I think all forms in Magento 2 will eventually be UI components.

But like @KAndy said, Magento 2 is currently a lot of ported code and inconsistencies.

Comment: do you know a tutorial (exclude official) that show how to create a form with ui component for frontend?